# $ionicScrollDelegate not working in ion-side-menu angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently working on $ionicScrollDelegate in my mobile app. My objectives is when the user click the header bar, it will scroll to top automatically.The problem I have right now is when I include the ion-side-menu in my code, the $ionicScrollDelegate cannot scroll back, I created a button which it returns their position, but cannot scroll back. I am trying to figure out why $ionicScrollDelegate cannot scroll back to top when I included the side menu but when I removed the side menu, the $ionicScrollDelegate seems to work fine and it can scroll back to top.

Working code - without ion-side-menu

```
 <ion-view>
                <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                    <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleLeft()" menu-toggle="left">
                        <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                    </button>

                    <h1 class="title">Details </h1>


                </ion-header-bar>
                <ion-content delegate-handle="mainContent" ng-controller="detailCtrl">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="loadMore(data)">Load More</a>
                    <ion-list can-swipe="listCanSwipe">

                        <ion-item ng-repeat="data in tempData |limitTo: limit"
                                  item="data"
                                  href="#/expenseDetail/{{data.id}}"
                                  class="item-remove-animate">

                            Date:{{data.modifiedDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}<br />

                            <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                                               ng-click="showPopup(data)">
                                Delete
                            </ion-option-button>
                            <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                                               ng-click="edit(data)"
                                               ng-disabled="data.status!= 'Draft'">
                                Edit
                            </ion-option-button>

                        </ion-item>

                    </ion-list>
                    <button class="button button-icon ion-android-arrow-up" ng-click="scrollListToTop()">Scroll Top</button>
                </ion-content>
<ion-view>
```

Not working - With side menu

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleLeft()" menu-toggle="left">
                    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
                </button>

                <h1 class="title">Expenses Details</h1>

                <a class="button button-icon ion-plus-round" href="#/addExpensesForm"></a>

            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content delegate-handle="mainContent" ng-controller="detailCtrl">
                <a href="#" ng-click="loadMore(data)">Load More</a>
                <ion-list can-swipe="listCanSwipe">

                    <ion-item ng-repeat="data in tempData |limitTo: limit"
                              item="data"
                              href="#/expenseDetail/{{data.id}}"
                              class="item-remove-animate">


                        Date:{{data.modifiedDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd"}}<br />
                 <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                                           ng-click="showPopup(data)">
                            Delete
                        </ion-option-button>
                        <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                                           ng-click="edit(data)"
                                           ng-disabled="data.status!= 'Draft'">
                            Edit
                        </ion-option-button>

                    </ion-item>

                </ion-list>
                <button class="button button-icon ion-android-arrow-up" ng-click="scrollListToTop()">Scroll Top</button>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>


        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
                <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
            </header>

            <ion-list>
                <ul class="list">
                    <a ui-sref="tabs.home" class="item">Home</a>
                    <a ui-sref="about" class="item">About</a>
                    <a ui-sref="tabs.setting" class="item">Settings</a>
                </ul>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
</ion-view>
```

In My controller, I have

```
$scope.scrollListToTop = function () {
        var result = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainContent').getScrollPosition();

        alert('Result:' + result.top + " " + result.left);
        //$ionicScrollDelegate._instances[2].scrollTop();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Big I just wanted to check what you thought of the answer I posted below. Work for you?

Comment: I have the same problem ( Still found no solution

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to your markup structure.

Both the links below suggest that `ion-side-menu-content` should contain an `ion-nav-bar` then an `ion-nav-view`

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu/blob/master/templates/menu.html and http://mcgivery.com/understanding-ionics-side-menu/

Switching that around and putting your ion-content in there may give you back control.

Drop us a codepen or similar if not.